# Can the return expression be just in one point of a recursive method of one type in java?

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write a string-type recursive method to make a string of specific and non-duplicate characters. The problem is that I got missing return statement error. The method is as follows:
any idea to fix it?

```
public static String makeString(char[] inputArray, int strLength, String str) {
    if (str.length() == strLength) {
        return str;
    }
    int l = inputArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        str += inputArray[i];
        int k = 0;
        char[] copyInput = new char[l - 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                copyInput[k] = inputArray[j];
                k++;
            }
        }
        makeString(copyInput, strLength, str);
        str = str.length() == 1 ? "" : str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Each method that does not have `void` as return type must have exactly one `return` on each execution path as last statement of that execution path. There is no special treatment of recursive methods. Try adding `return str;` at the end of the method.

Comment: I did this, but it ended up with just one empty string as output

Comment: Well that is a different problem, isn't it?

Comment: I have updated my answer adding some hints wrt. the method always returning an empty `String`. If this does not help, I recommend opening a new post.

Comment: No, as the method does, an empty string will be created at the end of the for in the first execution .This empty string is ignored by the recursive call.You know in void mode this method gives the correct output!

Comment: What do you mean with "*void mode*"?

Comment: This is a different method. And as I said before: you have asked about a compilation error. This should be fixed now. Debugging the application is not scope of this post since [each post should contain only one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: 'public static void makeString(char[] inputArray, int strLength, String str) {
        if (str.length() == strLength) {
            System.out.print(str + ", ");
            return;
        }[...]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each method that does not have `void` as return type must have one `return` on each execution path. There is no special treatment of recursive methods. The presented method is missing a `return`-statement for the execution path where the outer `if` is not entered.

This error can be fixed by adding `return str;` at the end of the method:

```
public static String makeString(char[] inputArray, int strLength, String str) {
    [...]
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        [...]
    }
    return str;
}
```

---

A remark on your code: We know from the [documentation of `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) that

> ... String objects are immutable ...

The code presented does not utilize the value returned from the recursive call and since Strings are immutable, the recursive call does not have any effect on the result. Since I do not fully understand your algorithm, I can only speculate that maybe you meant to write `str = makeString(copyInput, strLength, str);` instead of `makeString(copyInput, strLength, str);`.